# Pass value from view to controller in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to take value from view and pass it to my controller. I want to create a small form which contains two text fields and the value entered in each would get stored in a variable in the controller.

My View Code

```
<h1>App</h1>
<h3>Enter Your Geolocation</h3>

<% form_tag  get_GeoLocation do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :my_longitude %>
    <%= text_field_tag :my_latitude %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller i want to get values entered by user in the view and then do something with them. Please advice. I am using rails 4.2.0

Comment: Please read the documentation.  This is pretty basic stuff.  
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

You might want to go over a basic Rails tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
which will definitely help you get oriented, including on how to submit and handle form data.

Comment: can you tell me which section, i read this one it seems to be explaining how to post something to a database by getting values from view but i just want to store value in variable. Thanks so much again

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller

Comment: thanks @BenPolinsky got it. i can even upvote you if you post it as an answer. thanks bunch

Comment: @BenPolinsky will accept it in 3 minutes i can't accept your answer just yet. Thanks again.

Comment: @BenPolinsky also if you can remove my negative rep on question would be great. thanks

Comment: it wasn't me :) but looks like someone did remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these tutorials, the last link specifically

```
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller
```

Comment: hi i just posted a new question i am still kind of lost i think you might be able to help me . please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461755/storing-user-input-value-in-controller