# How can I send values from an erb file to a ruby controller?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to create a dynamic quiz system as follows:

1. A controller passes a value to an erb file (which creates an html
   form with the first quiz question)
2. The erb file has an html form where the user can enter an input
3. The erb file sends the input back to an action in the controller
4. The action checks the input value and loads the next question. The next 
   question depends on what the user's input was.

Now I know that I can send a value from an action to its corresponding erb file. Basic stuff. But how can I send a value from the erb file back to the controller (so that it can process the input from the html form)?

For example, this is what the html template (question1.html.erb) for the first question looks like:

```
<head ><title >Question 1</title ></head >
 <body>
    <form action="localhost:3000/welcome/processQ1" method = "get"> 
        <p>What is the sum of 5 + 6 ?</p> 
        <input name='sum' type='text' width='5' id='sum' required /> 
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' /> 
    </form >
</body>
```

What I want is to send the value of 'sum' back to an action called "processQ1" in the controller. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass value from view to controller in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461116/pass-value-from-view-to-controller-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, try always use the Rails way instead html pure tags for create your forms:

```
<%= form_for :quiz do |f| %>
  <label>What is the sum of 5 + 6 ?</label>
  <%= f.text_field :answer %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

After submit, in your controller you will get the value of answer in your `ProcessQ1` (This is not a good name for a controller because they are written in plural and more generically. So, for your purpose, `QuizzesController` is an option) in `params` rails hash variable on your action create.

ex: `{ quiz: {answer: 5 }}` and make anything you want with this data.

Please, read this docs. It is a good way to understand this processes of framework.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller

Comment: ProcessQ1 isn't the name of the controller. It is the name of the action in the controller. This action is supposed to receive the answer to the first question. I plan on creating more actions like ProcessQ2 (for processing the user input for the 2nd questions), ProcessQ3, etc. So assuming that the controller is called quiz_controller.rb, how can I pass the value of :answer to the action ProcessQ1?

Comment: Create a route for your action, pass in your form with param `<%= form_for @quiz, url: your_new_route %>` and get the value of params with `param` rails variable. ex: `params[:quiz][:answer]. So, you will understand this very well reading the docs.